# How to determine which Gradle configuration is active during runtime?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have several possible configurations for my project, each runs it's own task during the 'make' phase. How can I determine which configuration is selected? Alternatively, determining which task was run will serve jsut the same.

Comment: I have added an answer in response to your query. Please upvote and mark it as correct if this answer has helped you :)

Comment: Dear downvoter - downvoting is legit and all, but specifying a reason for doing that would be nice, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible through checking the BuildConfig.java file which gets generated. BuildConfig.java is generated automatically and it gets placed into the gen folder.

Suppose in your app module's build.gradle file, you have this buildType configuration :

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }

        preRelease {
            // Pre release code over here.
        }

        debugConfiguration {
            // Debug configuration code over here
        }
}
```

**And, in case you select your buildVariant as release, this BuildConfig.Java file gets generated...**

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.yourapp.packagename";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "release";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
}
```

Hence, if you wish to perform some action based on the build variant, you could try something like this...

```
final String buildType = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;

switch(buildType) {

    case "release" :
        // code for release build
        break;

    case "preRelease" :
        // code for preRelease build
        break;

    case "debugConfiguration" :
        // code for debugConfiguration build
        break;
}
```

**NB : I'm not sure if this is the recommended or the best way of dealing with this issue. There have been known issues with this approach** Check this link http://www.digipom.com/be-careful-with-buildconfig-debug/

What I would recommend is that you could set the build type flag manually to take care of this issue. For instance you could use this and perform actions based on this flag... **RECOMMENDED**

```
public class BuildTypeFlag {

    // set this to release, debug, or prerelease manually for your requirements...
    public static final BuildTypeEnum BUILD_TYPE_ENUM = RELEASE;

    public enum BuildTypeEnum {

        RELEASE, DEBUG, PRERELEASE, DUMMY_CONFIG

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm interested in determining the run configuration, not the build type.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? What do you exactly mean by run configuration? By run configuration I thought you referred to "debug" or "release" build configuration.

Comment: I didn't invent this term, thats how it's called in Android Studio. It is used to define which Gradle tasks will be run before 'make' is executed.